# axios postdata does not show image instead shows only path url in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have created a basic ReactJS application to perform crud operations using forms and an API,
I have successfully created the application to perform all the crud operations, but the only problem I have faced is that adding an image upload field in the form and uploading the image I'm only able to see the image path in both console and in the API, and I have same display of image path in the read page of the uploaded details.

I have given my code for both creating and reading of the application, verify them and help me with the proper solution to get through.

Create.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Form } from 'semantic-ui-react'
import axios from 'axios';
import { useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

function Create() {
    let navigate = useNavigate();

    const [image, setImage] = useState('');
    const [companyName, setCompanyName] = useState('');

    const postData = () => {

        const url = `https://62a6f21797b6156bff833b05.mockapi.io/CRUD`

            if(companyName.length <= 3){
                return Swal.fire({
                    icon: 'error',
                    title: 'Error',
                    text: 'All fields are mandatory!',
                    showConfirmButton: true
                  })
            }else{
                axios.post(url, {
                    image,
                    companyName
                })
    
            .then(() => {
                navigate('/company/list');
            })
            }
            
    }

    return (
        
        <div>
            <Form className="create-form">
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Image</label>
                    <input type="file" accept='image' onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.value)} />
                </Form.Field>
                <Form.Field>
                    <label>Company Name</label>
                    <input  placeholder='Company Name' onChange={(e) => setCompanyName(e.target.value)}/>
                </Form.Field>
                <Button color="blue" onClick={postData} type='submit'>Submit</Button>
            </Form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Create;
```

Read.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Table, List } from 'semantic-ui-react';


function Read() {

    const [APIData, setAPIData] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`https://62a6f21797b6156bff833b05.mockapi.io/CRUD`)
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data)
                setAPIData(response.data);
            })
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <Table singleLine>
                <Table.Body>
                    {APIData.map((data) => {
                        return (
                            <Table.Row>
                                <Table.Cell>
                                    <List>
                                        <List.Item>
                                                {data.image}
                                        </List.Item>
                                        <List.Item>
                                                {data.companyName}
                                        </List.Item>
                                    </List>
                                </Table.Cell>
                            </Table.Row>
                        )
                    })}
                </Table.Body>
            </Table>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Read;
```

With my knowledge over ReactJS I'm feeling that the problem would be with the way I'm using the axios for posting image data. I'm not that good with using axios so I might have mistaken the axios function for posting image.

Help me solving the problem I'm facing with necessary solution for posting image data from axios.

Answer (score 0):

At first you should get the file from the input slightly different:

```
<input type="file" accept='image' onChange={(e) => setImage(e.target.files[0])} />
```

And it's easier to send files via `FormData`, so try this:

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append('file', image);
data.append('name', companyName);
axios.post(url, data);
```

I don't know what do you use for backend, but you should handle server side too.

Comment: For now I'm not working with backend, I'm  using the localstorage to store and get data and little help of a jsonplaceholder api.